# Storing multiple sys.argv within a variable

Tags: python-3.x

I am having troubles storing `sys.argv` into a variable within my code.

It sounds easy but how do I make it check for multiple `sys.argv` to put into variable within my code?

As well as using regex on the `sys.argv`.

Comment: "but I do I make it check for multiple sys.argv": did you mean "but *how* do I make it check for multiple sys.argv"? Otherwise I don't understand your question

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. My mistake. I forgot to add how do I make it work with regex also.

Comment: Then please edit your question to fix the typo. And while you are at it, add whatever helps clarifying your question.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.argv` is simply a list, like any other Python list. Hence you can do things like `len(sys.argv)` to get the number of items in the list, and `sys.argv[4]` to get the fifth item in the list (ensuring, of course, that you don't try to access an item beyond the list end).

By way of example, this little script outputs its arguments (including the first one, the script itself):

```
import sys
for i in range(len(sys.argv)):
    print('Argument #%d is "%s"' % (i, sys.argv[i]))
```

Running that with `python3 testprog.py a b c d e` gives:

```
Argument #0 is "testprog.py"
Argument #1 is "a"
Argument #2 is "b"
Argument #3 is "c"
Argument #4 is "d"
Argument #5 is "e"
```

---

In terms of how you use regular expressions on the arguments, you just have to realise that it's a list of *strings.* So anything you can do do a string is fair game here.

So, as another example, this script will, when given two arguments, check to see if the string in the second argument matches the regular expression in the first:

```
import sys
import re
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Usage: testprog <regex> <string>")
elif re.fullmatch(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]) is None:
    print("No match")
else:
    print("Match")
```

And a sample run:

```
pax> python3 testprog.py
Usage: testprog <regex> <string>

pax> python3 testprog.py '[a-z]{4}' 'hello'
No match

pax> python3 testprog.py '[a-z]{4}' 'hell'
Match
```

Comment: I forgot to mention. How would I mix all this if I wanted to use regex?